# PHP save HTML on DOMDocument

Tags: php, html, dom, tags, domdocument

```
$html = <<<HTML
<div class="hey">test</div>
<div id="no">bla</div>
<div class="hey"><b>sa</b> hey<div id="l">b</div></div>  
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$q = '//div[@class="hey"]';
$arr = $xpath->query($q);
foreach($arr as $el) {
    echo $el->nodeValue;
}
```

I have this code above, but it doesn't save the html inside the class "hey". How can I save the HTML inside the divs?

Answer (score 0):

Try `$e1->textContent` instead of `$e1->nodeValue`

[textContent](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.textcontent)

> This attribute returns the text content of this node and its descendants.

[nodeValue](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nodevalue)

> The value of this node, depending on its type

Answer (score 0):

you may use saveXML or saveHTML with the optional contextNode-argument(set it to $el) to get the string.
This string will also contain `div.hey` , remove it via RegExp.

Please Note: saveHTML supports the optional contextNode since version 5.3.6